# Magento: Prove customer checked terms and condition checkbox

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Does anybody know if there is prove or a log that a customer checked the terms and conditions box at the checkout page? We need this for our payment provider to prove that the customer has checked the box.

Hope someone can give us this answer.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Logging the checkbox state is not standard with Magento and would need to be implemented using 3rd party customizations.

The proof can be based on the fact that they placed the order.  If the Terms & Condition checkbox is required, the only way for them to proceed to place the order would be to check the box.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. We have been looking for a module, but can not find any thing. Do you know what module can be used?

Comment: Terms and Conditions functionality is already included with Magento.  Look under `Sales > Terms and Conditions`, add a new condition.  It will appear to the user as a checkbox on the checkout page.

Comment: Dear Axel, Thanks for your reply. We have also the checkbox enabled and it is working properly. We only need a function that you get a log file with prove that customers have checked the checkbox when they place an order. We need this prove for one of our payment providers. Let me know if there is such a module?

Comment: As stated, there isn't anything that I know of.  The order records can't serve as a record of proof?  The only way an order can be made is if the user checked the box.  I would convey that to your payment providers.